# Blocking generator only seems to generate for one value. Why?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have this code:

This is my generator code:

```
from time import sleep


mock_sf_record = '{"payload": ...}'


def generateMessages():
    sleep(5)
    yield mock_sf_record
```

and the code that calls this code:

```
async def subscribe(subscription):
    global RECEIVED_MESSAGES_CACHE
    ...
    while True:
        messageStream = next(generateMessages()) if ENV == 'dev' else await websocket.recv()
```

The code that is calling `subscribe`:

```
 for subscription in SUBSCRIPTION_TYPES:
        loop.create_task(subscribe(subscription))
    loop.run_forever()
```

So, `SUBSCRIPTION_TYPES` is an array of 3 subscriptions. But, this only generates a stream messages for a single subscription and I never seem to generate messsages for any other subscription... it seems to block on a single thread. But it does generate several messages but only for a single subscription. Why is this? I think the generator is blocking... but I'm not sure why.

Comment: So it does generate more than once. It  generates several messages but only for a single subscription.

Comment: Why is `generateMessages` a generator function if you only call `next` on its return value once?

Comment: it's wrapped in a while True block already

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite make out what your generator is doing, but I think the main problem is your infinite loop. If I understand correctly, you only need to iterate until you exhaust the generated messages.

```
async def subscribe(subscription):
    global RECEIVED_MESSAGES_CACHEmessages = generateMessages()
    ...
    for message in messages
        messageStream = message if ENV == 'dev' else await websocket.recv()
        # Do something with messageStream
```